# My slider in java does not give same look and feel in all platform

Tags: java, swing

Hi I have created a slider in java in linux platform. But the slider gave different look and feel in different operating systems. Means in linux it looks little bit good but in mac operating system the slider looks different. so how to give same look and feel to my slider irrespective of operating system

The code is given below.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; import javax.swing.JSlider; import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

static int percent = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    final JSlider s = new JSlider();
    f.getContentPane().add(s);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    Timer time = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    percent++;
                    if (percent>100)
                            percent = 0;

// s.setMajorTickSpacing(10); //s.setMinorTickSpacing(1); //s.setPaintTicks(true); //s.setPaintLabels(true);

// JScrollBar sb = s.getHorizontalScrollBar(); s.setValue((int)(s.getMaximum()*(percent/100.0))); s.setAutoscrolls(true); } }); time.start(); }

}
```

Thanks
Sunil kumar Sahoo

Comment: well, the point of different look and feels is, that they look differently. but check out nimbus or metal, they are supposed to look almost the same on every platform

Comment: (Note, you shouldn't use Swing from any thread other than the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) including the main thread. Wrap the code in the standard boilerplate: `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnbale() { public void run() { ... }});`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the look and feel of the swing components by using

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName() );
```

or some other values defined by [UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#getInstalledLookAndFeels%28%29);